# How to find what is causing the debug run-time dependency in release build

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

My C++ project building in VS2015 output a DLL file. This project depend on vagarious *.lib files. When I check the output DLL with dependency walker, it shows it depend on VCRUNTIME140D.DLL. But I build the project in release mode.

So Is there anyway to find what it cause to link against debug run-times even though I build the project with release mode.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually be able to see what exactly causes the dependency through Dependency Walker. I created a sample solution with two projects that output a DLL. First of the projects links against the second, and the second uses debug runtime even in release mode, so building the first dll project in release mode would output a dll that references both - the release and debug runtimes. This is what I get when examining the first dll with Dependency Walker:

[image: Dependency Walker showing both runtimes]

So as you see, by thoroughly examining the list of imported libraries you should be able to find out which one imports the debug version of the runtime.

**EDIT**

Ok, if the dependency comes from a `.lib` file then the best thing I can think of is:

1) Enable verbose linker output like this:

[image: Enable Verbose linker output]

2) Build and inspect the output window to see which `.lib` file triggers loading of the unwanted `.dll`, in my case it shows quite nicely that `MixedModeDll2.lib` triggers loading `MSVCRTD`:

[image: Verbose linking output example]

Comment: Actually my project statically linking. so depend on *.lib files not *.dll